# Bootstrap 4 tooltip hide is not working on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tooltip this is working fine but I want to disable it once user click on a buttons (remove tooltip) but `tooltip('hide')` is not working.

I also want to add again tooltip if user click on add tooltip button.

My code:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();


        $('.remove-tooltip').click(function(){
          $('.left-menu a').tooltip('hide');
   });

        $('.add-tooltip').click(function(){
          $('.left-menu a').tooltip('show');
   });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="p-4 left-menu">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip Title">
Tooltip Title</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip Title">
Tooltip Title</a>

<br><br>
<button class="add-tooltip">Add Tooltip</button>
<button class="remove-tooltip">Remove Tooltip</button>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There is no element with the class `left-menu`. Add it to `<div class="p-4">` and it works

Comment: `left-menu` added but still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old**

```
$('.left-menu a').tooltip('hide');
```

**Change**

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();


        $('.remove-tooltip').click(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
   });

        $('.add-tooltip').click(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
   });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="p-4 left-menu">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip Title">
Tooltip Title</a>
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip Title">
Tooltip Title</a>

<br><br>
<button class="add-tooltip">Add Tooltip</button>
<button class="remove-tooltip">Remove Tooltip</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated:

Replace `left-menu` in jquery to `p-4`

```
$(".remove-tooltip").click(function () {
  $('.p-4 a').tooltip('disable')
});

$(".add-tooltip").click(function () {
  $(".p-4 a").tooltip("show");
});
```

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/QWKVMGN

Comment: If you click the `[<>]` snippet editor, you do not need to use codepen

Comment: @mplungjan I find **Codepen** a better solution.

Comment: Except it can disappear

Comment: After click on "Remove Tooltip" button tooltip should not work but still if you hover on "Tooltip Title" its works instead of remove